# MATLAB evaluate height vector of a 3D matrix into a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d

I'm programming in MATLAB and want to make my code as efficient as possible.
But I'm encountering a problem.

I have a 3D matrix (row, column, heigth)
And a 2D matrix (row, column)

I would like to save the max value of the height column in the corresponding cell of the 2D matrix. This can be done with a for-loop.

```
for i=1:row
    for j=1:column
        2D(i,j)=nanmax(3D(i,j,:));
    end
end
```

But is there an other way too? Something like:

```
2D(mask)=3D(mask,nanmax(:));
```

with mask being a logical matrix, possible just containing ones to make it easier.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
twoD = nanmax( threeD, [], 3 );
```

If you have a mask, you may use a temporal variable

```
tmp = nanmax( threeD, [], 3 );
twoD(mask) = tmp(mask);
```

PS
[It is best not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: No, I'll try it right now. What does the [] exactly do?

Big thanks for responding so quickly!

Comment: @jasper.l see doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmax.html, the third use case.